# Alerts not functioning correctly on modern pages in communication site

Tags: sharepoint-online, alert, modern-pages

I have noticed while using the alerts on a Page library in a communication site that users (Readers) who can only see major versions (1.0, 2.0, 3.0) and set up to receive alerts when everything changes are instead receiving notifications when the page is 0.3, 0.4 etc. If the page is deleted when still in draft (even 0.1) they receive a notification. This did not seem it appeared with documents or items under version control before. Is this a bug?